# mongoose document.save not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to create a very simple forum using nodejs, mongo and mongoose.

So far I created a mongoose Schema for users:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var user = {
  _id: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true }
};

var schema = new mongoose.Schema(user);

module.exports = schema;
module.exports.user = user;
```

Then created the Model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/forum'

mongoose.connect(url);

mongoose.connection.on('connected', function() {
    console.log('Stablished connection on ' + url);
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function(error) {
    console.log('Something wrong happened: ' + error);
});
mongoose.connection.on('disconnected', function() {
    console.log('connection closed');
});

var User = mongoose.model('User', require('./user'));

module.exports.User = User;
```

Finally, there is the file that contains all the models (currently just one) and its methods:

```
var models = require('./models');

var User = models.User

exports.addUser = function(user, password) {
    var data = new User({ _id: user, password: password });
    data.save(function(error) {
        console.log('inside');
        if(error) { console.log('ERROR: ' + error); return true; }
        else { console.log('User ' + user + ' added'); return false; }
    });
};

exports.getUserList = function() {
    User.find().lean().exec(function(error, users) {
        if(error) { console.log('ERROR: ' + error); }
        else { return JSON.stringify(users); }
    });
}
```

The problem comes when I execute this file:

```
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var dm = require('./dm');

var users = { 'user1': '1234',
              'user2': '1234',
              'user3': '1234',
              'user4': '1234'
            };

console.log('Initial user list');
dm.getUserList();
for(var user in users) {
    dm.addUser(user, users[user]);
}
console.log('Final user list');
dm.getUserList();
process.exit(0);
```

It seems that it does nothing and does not save the users. Output:

```
Initial user list
Final user list
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your code assumes everything will run in synchronous manner. You need to either create the functions `addUser()` and `getUserList` to have callbacks or use `Promises` for this to work.

Comment: Added callbacks but still not working. The thing is that it seems that it is not entering the .save/.find function. For example, if I set User.find callback to a console.log it does not prompt anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `process.exit()` part, or wrap it in a timeout. You don't give your database enough time to execute. E.g. put this at the end instead:

```
...
setTimeout(() => process.exit(0), 2000);
```

Edit: or add promises, like somebody commented:

```
exports.addUser = function(user, password) {
  var data = new User({ _id: user, password: password });
  return data.save()
  .then(() => console.log('User ' + user + ' added'))
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('ERROR: ' + error);
    else {  return false; }
 });  
};
```

Then in your main loop:

```
const promises = users.map(userData => addUser(userData));
Promise.all(promises)
.then(() => {
  console.log('All users added.');
  // .. do another async operation here, or process.exit();
});
```

Comment: Thank you for ponting that setTimeout. Finally adding the setTimeout and using call backs works fine